# .Net Core API returns 405:Method not allowed when having Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a Asp.NET Core MVC application that `Controller` always gets invoked from the `View`. I am now extending the application by exposing new API endpoint which can be called from outside like Postman.

I am facing an issue of getting `405 - Method Not Allowed` when I put `[Authorize]` attribute on top of my controller. without this attribute I can hit the endpoint and the Model gets bounded with the values I provided from postman as expected.

Below is how my controller looks like:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/v1/auth")]
public class ApiAuthController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("changePassword")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordModel model)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

It might worth to mention that, this application is the same application that provides the Bearer token which I later use in the postman.

Below is the postman:
[image]

[image]

In my `Startup.cs` file I have the following settings related to `IdentityServer` and `Authorization`:

```
        services
            .AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
            .AddSigningCredential(cert)
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()               
            .AddAuthentication()
```

Comment: It would help if you can show how authorization is configured in your Startup.cs

Comment: ApiAuthController should inherit from ControllerBase and you should add the ApiController attribute.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, I doubt if that has to do anything with whether it's inherited from Controller or ControllerBase, I have tried with ControllerBase and same thing is happening.

Comment: @Benjamin Maybe you could try disabling _Automatically follow redirects_ in Postman - Settings - General. I wonder if IdentityServer is redirecting your request to the login page while preserving the POST method, which causes the 405 response.

Comment: @scharnyw, that was an interesting point. I disabled that option, and right now I am keep getting "302- Found" back. I still don't understand what prevents me reaching the method in the Controller.

Comment: can you try using the namespace using System.Web.Http; instead of using System.Web.Mvc;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you are not authenticated and IdentityServer is trying to redirect you either to login page or access denied page, hence the 302 response. Meanwhile Postman handles 302 in a way that is different from most web browsers, which is following the redirect but preserving the POST method (instead of changing to GET). This leads to a POST request to the login page that finally results in a 405 Method Not Allowed response.

This should not happen in most web browsers as they would change the HTTP method to GET upon receiving a 302 response. But to work around this issue for browsers or user agents that don't do this, you can try:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied =
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Method != "GET")
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        };
});
```

This should send a 401 Unauthorized response instead of a 302 response when the method is not GET.

Comment: Thanks, This answer helped me to narrow down the issue, Now I need to figure out why can't I authenticate using the Bearer token that I have.